# run exe file which is installed on the client machine from the web browser

Tags: html, browser, dll, activex

I have a small exe file written in VB.NET which connects to database, gets the last row and send the information to the printer. It is just a small part of a program but it uses special font and also calculates the widths for the printer.

I've developed the same program with PHP. Now almost every functionality of it is same wirh the windows based program. But the printing results of the web browser can't be same as I get with the exe file. So I want to just send a paramater to the exe file and run it. (with a javascript call or else) Exe file is on the client machine and I will know where it is the located.

Can you suggest me a way to do that.
I read that this is possible using dll or ocx.

I'm not familiar developing browser plugins.
Is there a tutorial or book for that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you've concatenated `"Security"`, `" "`, and `"risk"` together.

Comment: There is no security risk because this is not a public project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my machine suddenly asked me if it was ok for a website to download and run an exe, I'd have closed the window before the dialog had finished rendering.

The simplest thing to do here would be to fix the formatting of the php's output. Just because you can potentially execute an exe file on the client is a million miles away from meaning you should. Unless you know and have complete control over the users and the systems that those users are working on, any exe related system is going to be brittle at best and even if you do have that control, it's a bodge.

There are pdf libraries written for php that would permit you better control over your outputs, including fonts. There's a write up of one such library over at [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/generate-pdfs-php/).

Alternatively, you could probably turn your .NET app into a web app/service that your php could communicate with.

Comment: Hi JHolyhead, there will be no trust problem because the company members will use this system. The pdf libraries are good but I want to print out the page instantly when the user press "Print" button on the webpage. Is there a way for that? I also thought turning .NET app into a web app/service that php could communicate with. I will do it if I can't find another way.

Comment: If all you are doing is printing out some content from a web page, then I don't see why you can't achieve everything you need with a well thought-out print stylesheet. Maybe I'm missing some of the complexity of your problem, but it sounds like you are trying something quite a complicated solution for a fairly simple problem.

Comment: Actually this is not a webpage. It is a receipt of a transaction. However the output is specified for a unique printer.

Comment: what does the .NET output to the printer?

Comment: It automatically select the "unique printer name" (lets say PRINTER1. it is not default printer on the users machines) and send the data. I can create exactly same view with HTML. But the problem is that I want to instantly print it to the PRINTER1 without bothering with print dialog. Maybe there is a trick for it?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that in PHP, so turning your VB code into a web service is probably your best bet. I'd strongly advise using your client side exe approach as sooner or later, you'll need to release an update to that exe (printer name changes etc) and you'll suddenly have the nightmare of ensuring everyone has the right version. It will go wrong and it will be a nightmare.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that as well but I wanted to ask if there is another way. I'll create a web service and also provide a second option of manually printing from a webpage with print dialog. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Developing a browser plugin to do what you wan't isn't terribly difficult; I have to agree with JHolyhead that it'd be better to avoid doing this if you can, because there are some siginificant security considerations.

You'd need to know some C++ and you could use the [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) framework to write a plugin that would work on all platforms. Launching a process can be done using CreateProcessEx, and the main challenge you'll run into is that the process will be launched in low integrity mode in IE when you're on vista/win7 w/ UAC enabled (due to protected mode). The easiest fix for this is to just add the site to your list of trusted sites, but there are some ways to make it posible to launch the process is medium integrity (normal non-elevated) mode.

If you know C++ and have some experience with windows development, this would be very easy; if you don't, it might be a bit trickier. If there are other options (that dont' require you to install a browser plugin) you'd probably be better off following them. However, a basic FireBreath plugin can be thrown together in about 20 minutes (there are video tutorials).